# What is the name of font used in this design

Tags: font-identification

I have been searching the font name using font matching services but couldn't find any reference, can someone please tell me what font is used in this design?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it's [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat) to me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For font identificatin, use Photoshop they added font identification function!

1. Open the file (image) in Photoshop CC.
2. Drag a marquee around the font you want to identify.
3. Go to the top and select type > match font.